# Duplicating label from root window to top level window on tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have created a label as part of a function on root window. I want that exact same label to appear on toplevel window. How can i duplicate the label?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's preventing you from just creating another label? Also, what do you mean by "exact same label"? A single label can only be in one place at a time. Do you just want two labels that display the exact same data? Do you want to be able to change the color or size of one and have it automatically be reflected in another?

Comment: Tkinter widgets can't be moved from window to window. If you want the same text used in the first label to appear in the second, you can use `label2.config(text=label1.cget("text"))`. If you want to copy other attributes as well, like color, size, etc., it would be best just to create and use a custom label class with those settings set by default.

Comment: Thank you @SamMatzko - that's exactly what I wanted. Sorry, I am a total newbie at this and struggling with even the most basic of things!! Really appreciate your feedback despite the question being very unclear.

Comment: That's okay. Learning to be a part of the Stack Overflow community can be tough. I recommend reading [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); it should provide some insight on how to ask questions. I also recommend reading the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); this will give you more information about how Stack Overflow in general is run. Also, by reading it, you can earn a bronze badge!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information; Anyways I will write some code according to what I understand:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def foo():
    lbl = Label(root, text=“Text”)
    lbl_txt = lbl.text()
    lbl.pack()
    new_win = Toplevel()
    lbl2 = Label(new_win, text=lbl_txt)
    lbl2.pack()
btn = Button(root, text=“Show Label and Open Window”, command=foo)
btn.pack()
```

Hope that this helps! Thank You!